# Crear una session en archivo custom Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop1.7

¿Es posible crear una session desde un archivo custom prestashop?,
tengo restringido desde el frontController la navegación el la tienda si un usuario no  tiene una session.

```
 if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged() && $this->php_self !=  'authentication' && $this->php_self != 'password'){
         Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication?back=my-account');
    }
```

Ahora bien necesito acceder a las ciertos métodos de la herramienta desde un archivo custom (si incluyo primero el archivo init.php, verifica el estado de mi session y me redirige a login), hay forma de crear una session antes de incluir este archivo?, 
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

esto sirve para crear una session, por si le es de utilidad

```
$contexcookie= context::getContext()->cookie;
$contexcustomer= context::getContext()->customer;
$customer = new Customer((int)($customer->id));
$contexcookie->id_customer = (int)($customer->id);
$contexcookie->customer_lastname = $customer->lastname;
$contexcookie->customer_firstname = $customer->firstname;
$contexcookie->logged = 1;
$customer->logged = 1;
$contexcookie->is_guest = $customer->isGuest();
$contexcookie->passwd = $customer->passwd;
$contexcookie->email = $customer->email;
// Add customer to the context
$contexcustomer = $customer;
```